# Python search loop slow

Tags: python, search

I am running a search on a list of ads (adscrape). Each ad is a dict within adscrape (e.g. ad below). It searches through a list of IDs (database_ids) which could be between 200,000 - 1,000,000 items long. I want to find any ads in adscrape that don't have an ID already in database_ids.

My current code is below. It takes a loooong time, and multiple seconds for each ad to scan through database_ids. Is there a more efficient/faster way of running this (finding which items in a big list, are in another big list)?

```
database_ids = ['id1','id2','id3'...]
ad = {'body': u'\xa0SUV', 'loc': u'SA', 'last scan': '06/02/16', 'eng': u'\xa06cyl 2.7L ', 'make': u'Hyundai', 'year': u'2006', 'id': u'OAG-AD-12371713', 'first scan': '06/02/16', 'odo': u'168911', 'active': 'Y', 'adtype': u'Dealer: Used Car', 'model': u'Tucson Auto 4x4 ', 'trans': u'\xa0Automatic', 'price': u'9990'}

for ad in adscrape:
    ad['last scan'] = date
    ad['active'] = 'Y'
    adscrape_ids.append(ad['id'])
    if ad['id'] not in database_ids:
        ad['first scan'] = date
        print 'new ad:',ad
        newads.append(ad)
```

Comment: make database_ids to set will be much faster

Comment: @xfx it will take a while to form `set` from list above, also i think it's already set because id is unique...As i know fastest way to check that item in list is the way you are doing that `if item in list` ...'

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko list is not set even though it's items are unique. use database_ids = set(database_ids)

Comment: agree, sets is faster but time would be loosed while forming set ... @Testy8 at least you have to try converting to set as xfx suggested...

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko You're going to spend more time repeatedly doing list lookups than you will building a set to start.

Comment: Is this hardcoded somehow?  Why would it "take a while to make a set"?  And if it is hardcoded (which seems absurd) then change the source to `database_ids = {'id1', 'id2', 'id3', ...}`.

Answer (score 0):

`You can use list comprehensions for this as the code base given below. Use the existing database_ids list and adscrape dict as given above.

Code base:
new_adds_ids = [ad for ad in adscrape if ad['id'] not in database_ids]`

Comment: Please format any code in your answer using the code sample button.

Answer (score -1):

You can build `ids_map` as `dict` and check whether id in list by accessing key in that ids_map as in code snippet below:

```
database_ids = ['id1','id2','id3']
ad = {'id': u'OAG-AD-12371713', 'body': u'\xa0SUV', 'loc': u'SA', 'last scan': '06/02/16', 'eng': u'\xa06cyl 2.7L ', 'make': u'Hyundai', 'year': u'2006', 'first scan': '06/02/16', 'odo': u'168911', 'active': 'Y', 'adtype': u'Dealer: Used Car', 'model': u'Tucson Auto 4x4 ', 'trans': u'\xa0Automatic', 'price': u'9990'}

#build ids map
ids_map = dict((k, v) for v, k in enumerate(database_ids))

for ad in adscrape:
    # some logic before checking whether id in database_ids
    try:
        ids_map[ad['id']]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    else:
        #error not thrown perform logic for existed ids
        print 'id %s in list' % ad['id']
```